Pydantic not able to validate recursively defined types at runtime
I am trying to encapsulate Json-serializability with Pydantic.
By nature, Json format is recursive, as in, a json field can be a list of or a dict of any valid json field. I tried to replicate this using Pydantic.
BasicJsonSerializableType = Union[str, int, float, bool, None]
JsonSerializableType = Union[BasicJsonSerializableType, "JsonSerializableDictType", "JsonSerializableListType"]
JsonSerializableListType = list[JsonSerializableType]
JsonSerializableDictType = dict[BasicJsonSerializableType, JsonSerializableType]

On a higher level everything seems to be working. However I am getting some validation errors down the line, where error messages such as the following occur:
[2024-06-24T12:29:34Z] [REDACTED]: error: Dict entry 5 has incompatible type "str": "list[dict[str, str]]"; expected "str | int | float | None": "str | int | float | JsonSerializableDictType | JsonSerializableListType | None"  [dict-item]

Pydantic is not able to validate "str": "list[dict[str,str]]" against "str": JsonSerializableListType, where JsonSerializableListType is allowed to be list[JsonSerializableType], where JsonSerializableType is allowed to be a dict[str, str]
I tried to go through files with validation errors to land type definition to non-typed fields, however I quickly realized some could not be type-validated. I tried to update_forward_refs but as my types are not special classes but a union of built-in types they do not implement update_forward_refs.

Try https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/types/#pydantic.types.JsonValue
